# LDAP minimum password length

Tags: ldap

I have successfully configured LDAP server on rhel7.2 and can successfully login to any LDAP client.

I have also integrated password policy in ldap.

Problem is that when I am changing password on LDAP client with mere 5 characters, it is not giving me any error message and changing LDAP user password successfully.

Please find below my LDAP server password policy.

Code:

```
[LDAP Server]# ldapsearch -x -b cn=default,ou=policies,dc=domain,dc=com -H ldap://<LDAP Server>

# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3    
# base <cn=default,ou=policies,dc=domain,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#
# default, policies, domain.com    
dn: cn=default,ou=policies,dc=domain,dc=com
cn: default
objectClass: pwdPolicy
objectClass: device   
objectClass: top    
pwdAttribute: userPassword    
pwdMaxAge: 2592000    
pwdInHistory: 4    
pwdCheckQuality: 1    
pwdMinLength: 14    
pwdMaxFailure: 3    
pwdLockout: TRUE    
pwdGraceAuthNLimit: 0    
pwdFailureCountInterval: 0    
pwdMustChange: TRUE    
pwdAllowUserChange: TRUE    
pwdSafeModify: FALSE    
pwdLockoutDuration: 1800    
pwdExpireWarning: 2073600    

# search result    
search: 2    
result: 0 Success    
# numResponses: 2    
# numEntries: 1
```

I have followed the below link:

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2710021

I am changing password on LDAP server by:

```
# ldappasswd -x -D "cn=Manager,dc=domain,dc=com" -W -S 
"uid=ldapuser,ou=People,dc=domain,dc=com"
New password:    
Re-enter new password:    
Enter LDAP Password:
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using what looks like the root DN, this bypasses the password policy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!!!...........how can i correct this??